# Execute query on SQL Server Analysis Services with IronPython

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, ironpython

I was able to connect to SQL server Analysis service in Python using `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll`, and now I can't execute query on cube.

I've tried `Execute` method same as following:

```
amoServer.Execute('select from finance')
```

After issuing `Execute` method I have this error:

```
<Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaError object at 0x000000000000002B [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaError]>
```

Note: I'm using IronPython with Python 2.7 on Windows Server 64Bit.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

its better use **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll** and **mdx** query.
and set query result in Datasets in **Ststem.Data** assembly
something like this:

```
clr.AddReference ("Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll")
clr.AddReference ("System.Data")

from Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient import AdomdConnection , AdomdDataAdapter
from System.Data import DataSet

conn = AdomdConnection("Data Source=0.0.0.0;Catalog=MyCatalog;")
conn.Open()
cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
cmd.CommandText = "your mdx query" # in your case 'select from finance'
adp = AdomdDataAdapter(cmd)
datasetParam =  DataSet()
adp.Fill(datasetParam)
conn.Close();

# datasetParam hold your result as collection a\of tables
# each tables has rows
# and each row has columns
print datasetParam.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
```

Comment: thanks a lot Behrooz... this solution works correctly.

Comment: thx, I am able to use this to fill the dataset, but is there a good example on how to parse the dataset to get back a structure similar to a sql resultset?

Comment: Will the solution work with Azure Analysis Service as well?

Comment: Currently (VS2017) you must omit the ".dll" from the first AddReference