# Connecting R or Python to an Analysis Services Cube (Microsoft)?

Tags: python, sql, r, analysis, cube

I'm trying to connect R or Python to an Analysis Services Cube. I usually access it through Excel Analysis Services, with the URL of the remote server and my username and password. You can see how I access it in the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thereafter I get a pivotable that allows me to make some queries. I need to do the same with R or Python, especially to import data. I tried to use [olapR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/r/using-data-from-olap-cubes-in-r?view=sql-server-2017) but I don't know how to set the server URL, username, and password. I also tried to use [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723438/execute-query-on-sql-server-analysis-services-with-ironpython) but it doesn't work for me.

Do you know if there is a tutorial or can you help me?

Note: I have "only read" permission, so I cannot change the configuration of the cube.

Comment: Have you tried ODBC? If the data is not over-dimensioned, it might work for you. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/supported-data-sources-ssas-multidimensional?view=asallproducts-allversions